# Gradle Idea plugin - issues with specifing test sources

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a custom source set and mark its contents in Intellij Idea as a Test Sources Root. I tried to use *idea plugin* and do it according to the [gradle official website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html#sec:idea_identify_additional_source_sets) but it is not clear for me how it works.

First of all the documentation specifies the following configuration setup

```
    idea {
        module {
            testSources.from(sourceSets["intTest"].java.srcDirs)
        }
    }
```

When I try to use it i receive **Unresolved reference: testSources**. Where is it coming from?

Then I tried to use:

```
    idea {
        module {
            testSourceDirs = intTest.java.srcDirs
        }
    }
```

it works fine as long as I use only Java. After applying *Kotlin plugin* however, both kotlin and java + resources folder are again treated as Sources Root not Test Sources. To fix that I had to change from:

```
            testSourceDirs = intTest.java.srcDirs
```

to:

```
            testSourceDirs = intTest.kotlin.srcDirs
```

and now all folders are Test Source Root again. Since kotlin.srcDirs also includes java.srcDirs it looks like you have to specify all, otherwise it is ignored...

Now the real issue came when I used [gradle-avro-plugin](https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin). Applying it made my folders marked as Sources Root again. I believe it is because it adds another avro directory, but just to main source set.

Does anyone know how to make it marked as Test Sources having both kotlin and avro plugin applied? Am I doing something wrong here? Beacause this beheviour seems to be buggy in the first place.

Tested with:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
- Gradle 6.8.3 and 7.4.2
- Plugin id("com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro") version "1.5.0"
- Plugin kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.0"

Comment: Why is this necessarily to have it marked as Test sources? it will work just the same with source roots.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to use it i receive Unresolved reference: testSources. Where is it coming from?

Please try using getTestSources(). The reference below says it will support it from IDEA 2021.

reference : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19645#issuecomment-1022309483

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35570422)